# Page not found codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to install a codeigniter app. But only the home page is working... 
Here is my files :
**config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/folder/subfolder/";
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

**routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller']    = "home";
$route['search']                = "search/index";
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine ON 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
Options All -Indexes
```

And I'm trying to get *http://localhost/folder/subfloder/search* or an other controller, I have a 404 page not found. The home url works fine.

Where is the problem?

Thanks!

**Solution found :**

The only thing to add was : `RewriteBase /folder/subfolder/`

Comment: Have you made sure your controller file names and class names have first letter as upper case? Example Home.php and Search.php and some more htaccess here to try https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: No, files are in lower case. But functions have first letter as upper case.

Comment: Thanks for your link, it helps me to find the solution! :) The only thing to add was : RewriteBase /folder/subfolder/

Comment: Your welcome I thought I would share the ones I have tried so made repo on git hub.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `.htaccess` to(Works with sub-domain)

```
# Enforce www
# If you have subdomains, you can add them to 
# the list using the "|" (OR) regex operator
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|subdomain) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

# Enforce NO www
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the following HTaccess for all CodeIgniter installations:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

It's the HTAccess from Laravel, never let me down!